# Rationale after the "literal" expression `where T : class` in C#

Tags: c#, generics, types, type-constraints

In C#, one is allowed to write:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : class {

}
```

And according to the C# specifications, this means that:

> The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Some are of the opinion that the **literal** statement `T : class` is confusing, one could see it as.

> The type argument must be a class type. So interfaces and delegates are not allowed. (**wrong**)

Where for instances interfaces and delegates are **not** allowed. I'm wondering if the C# design team considered this and why they didn't introduce a constraint like:

```
where T : reference
```

(Or another keyword that is more precise). What was the rationale to use `: class` instead?

Comment: Aren't interfaces, delegates, and array types considered reference types anyway?

Comment: A struct can implement interfaces, passing a struct as an interface boxes it though. Also question is unanswerable without having attended the meetings of the C# team at the time of picking the keyword.

Comment: Fixed typo. Well the instances of interfaces are indeed classes. And can see a delegate as some kind of class which delegates that function. But at type-level classes and interfaces are something else...

Comment: @JohanLarsson: not entirely, since once one specifies `T : class`, one can assign `T variable = null;` (without specifying `T` is not a struct). Thus it seems that the `: class` implies "no `struct`"

Comment: Unless a member of the C# language design team happens to be around, we can only try to read their minds or give personal opinions. Thus, an off-topic question on SO.

Comment: @chris: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rationale+behind with 1k+ questions only twelve downvoted, this is debatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They wanted to stick to a keyword that was already present in the language. Surely `reference` or `referencetype` would be more precise.

Similarly, it is called `where T : struct`, not `valuetype` (or `nonnullablevaluetype`), even if both `struct`s and `enum`s are value types that can be used for `T` in that case. Also note that the special struct `Nullable<>` is not allowed if the constraint `where T : struct` was used.

Comment: But this is, in my opinion because a `Nullable` is a `class`, it's not a `struct`. It's a `class` that embeds a `struct` value (and a boolean whether the result is indeed `null`). And indeed, they wrote some syntactical sugar around it.

Comment: @CommuSoft No, `Nullable<>` is a (special) struct. If it were a `class`, you would be able to use e.g. the type `int?` (a.k.a. `Nullable<int>`) for the "`T`" when the constraint `where T : class` is used.

Comment: You're right: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Nullable@cs/1305376/Nullable@cs but that makes it quite weird why it is not allowed...

Comment: @CommuSoft Just read the C# Language Specification. The `Nullable<>` type has semantics that are different from a usual value type (other boxing semantics, and lifted operators, etc.). It is also not a reference type. So it has its own category that is neither `where T : class` nor `where T : struct`. It ***is*** allowed with `where T : new()`, however.

Comment: Indeed. Many thanks for figuring this out. It is quite "schizophrenically" designed (neither struct nor class, not that this is inherently bad of course). They probably wanted to retain the copy-by-assignment semantics. But it makes life quite complicated (especially with regards to backwards compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

```
where T: class
```

reads

```
where T: <reference type>
```

I'm not sure why it was called class, though. Someone who was sitting through the language team's meetings on that one might have to chime in.